# R : N samples with rnorm()

Tags: r

I'm starting with R code. Do you know please how to generate 1000 samples of size 100 with rnorm() function ? My code is :

```
#Loi Normale

 n<-100

 ech<-rnorm(n)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `replicate`:

```r
replicate(1000, rnorm(100), simplify = FALSE)
```

Comment: Thank you, why we add simplify = FALSE ?

Comment: De rien :) Check with and without. With `simplify = TRUE`, it returns a weird matrix, with `FALSE`, it returns a list that IMO easier to understand

Comment: Merci @Maël ! Can I use also "replicate" with runif function : ech3<-replicate(1000, runif(100)) ?

Comment: Yes. Check `?replicate` if you want to know more about this function